# SimPy Concurrency

Tags: python, simpy

I have a network simulation with SimPy. A packet is sent from the generator class (includes yield for 1.5s) to the Slot class (includes another yield for 1.5s) then to the wire class and then to the destination.
I need to detect collisions coming from different Slots to the wire class and they share the same timestamp.
However, simpy runs all events sequentially so if packet 1 from source 1 has a timestamp let's say 3, same as packet 1 from source 2, I cannot detect collision in wire since it passes p 1 s 1 first and then accepts p 1 s 2. I tried yielding for 1.5 in wire which solves the issue but causes propagation of delay in all packets.
Is there any other way to wait in wire for the second packet to arrive?

Class Slot:

```
yield self.env.timeout(slot_duration)
.
.
.
self.out.put(packet)  # Send packet to the out attribute (wire)
```

Class Wire:

```
while True:
            print("before packet yield and wire yield: ",self.env.now)
    
                if first_event:
                    yield self.env.timeout(1.5 + self.epsilon)  # Wait for epsilon time for the first event
                    print("End of first yield in wire for {} until {}".format(1.5 + self.epsilon, self.env.now))
                    first_event = False  # Set the flag to False after the first event
                else:
                    yield self.env.timeout(1.5)  # Wait for 1.5 time units for subsequent events
                    print("End of yield in wire until {}".format(self.env.now))
    
                num_items_in_store = len(self.store.items)
                print("Number of items in store:", num_items_in_store)
                # might be a problem here:
                # print("item 0 is: ", self.store.items[0])
                packet = self.store.items[0]
                packet_store_object = self.store.get() #yield self.store.get()
    
                colliding_packets = [] # reset
                print("poped packet from store:", packet)
                # current_time = self.env.now
    
                # if len(self.store.items) == 0:
                #     continue  # No packets arrived during epsilon time, so nothing to do
                if len(self.store.items) >= 1:
                    print("now current_time checking store for collision: ",self.env.now)
                    # Check for collisions using time packet entered wire
                    colliding_packets = [p for p in self.store.items if p.current_time == packet.current_time]
```

Comment: can you add a take method to your wire class that checks if its already processing a packet?

Comment: what suppose to happen if there is a collision?  Does the slot wait till the wire is finished with its current packet?  Does the second packet get dropped?

Answer (score -1):

This is not quite what you described, but...
here is a example where a wire processes only one packet at a time, and blocks while busy.  When a wire is busy, a slot will wait, until the wire is idle.  This example has only one wire and slot, but it should work if a wire is assigned to more then one slot.  The trick is I use a store with a capacity of one to bottleneck the flow.  The store is full while the wire is busy and empty when the wire is idle.  Since the store has a capacity of one, it will not accept a new packet while the wire is busy.

```
"""
Simple sim where a slot sends packets to a wire.

The wire uses a store as a semiphore to block incoming packets
until it has finished processing its current packet and is idle.  
So a wire will never have more then one packet, and a slot
will wait until a wire is idle

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class Packet():
    """
    packets that are being processed
    has a id for tracking
    """

    last_id = 0

    def __init__(self):
    
        self.__class__.last_id += +1

        self.id = self.__class__.last_id


class Wire():
    """
    Processes one packet at a time
    will not accept a packet if busy,
    like a store with capacity of one.
    """

    last_id = 0

    def __init__(self, env):

        self.__class__.last_id += 1
        self.id = self.__class__.last_id

        self.env = env

        # store is empty when wire is idle, full when busy
        self.store = simpy.Store(env, 1)

    def process_packet(self):
        """
        Processes the packet.

        pulls the packet from the store only when processing 
        has finished and wire is idle.
        """

        yield self.env.timeout(random.triangular(1,4,7))

        # done and is now idle, clear store to signal wire is idle
        p = yield self.store.get()
        print(self.env.now, f"wire {self.id} finished processing packet {p.id}")

    def q_packet(self, p):
        """
        queues the packet for processing
        and waits for the processing to start

        When wire is ready to process the packet,
        the packet is put into the store
        and the process to process the packet is started

        note the store is not a queue.
        the queue is store's put request queue that blocks when the store is at capacity
        """

        # if the store is full, then wire is busy, wait until wire is idle and store is empty
        yield self.store.put(p)

        # wire is idle, start processing packet
        print(self.env.now, f'wire {self.id} has started processing packet {p.id}')
        self.env.process(self.process_packet())

    
def slot(env, id, wire):
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.triangular(1, 3, 5))

        p = Packet()

        print(env.now, f'slot {id} is ready to send packet {p.id} to wire {wire.id}')

        # wait for wire to become idle
        yield env.process(wire.q_packet(p))
        print(env.now, f'slot {id} has sent packet {p.id} to wire {wire.id}')

env = simpy.Environment()

wire1 = Wire(env)
slot1 = env.process(slot(env,1,wire1))

env.run(100)
```